# calling an api inside map function and using the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

```
vm.owners = parents.children.map(function(e) {
  getparentById(e.Id)
    .then(function(getresponse) {
      var html = '<a href="/#/parent/onboard/' + e.Id + '"  target="_blank">' + e.Number + "-" + e.Name + "-" + getresponse.code + '</a>';
      return html;
    })
    .finally(function() {
      vm.isLoading = false;
    });
  // var html = '<a href="/#/parent/onboard/'+e.Id+'"  target="_blank">' + e.Number + "-" + e.Name + '</a>';
  // return html;
}).join('  ||  ');
```

Above code i am trying join html variable by || as it loops through children and calls an api through getparentbyid. if i put html outside getparentbyid function i can join html with '||' but i can't get code of getresponse to join with it. when i put it inside getparentbyid api call function i can't get output jouned with "||". i just get empty spaces joined by "||". how do i solve this?

Comment: @RandyCasburn  I think there is an answer there, but i can't understand those answers to solve it here yet

Comment: @DanO i tried those answers. did not work so far. may be i am trying them wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function parameter for `.map()` need to return something, currently it doesn't. Add a `return` statement before the `getparentById()` call and it will return the Promise it creates.

The `map()` call will then return an array of these Promises, which should all resolve. You can use `Promise.all()` for that, which will return a single Promise. Use `.then()` on this Promise to use the resulting array of texts. which can be joined then.

`vm.owners` can only be assigned in this `.then()` callback, because the result will be available only after all `getParentById()` calls are completed.

You set `vm.isLoading = false` after building each single link. I suppose, you want to move that code. You can use `finally()` just after the last `.then()`

This will look like:

```
Promise.all(parents.children.map(function(e) {
  return getparentById(e.Id)
    .then(function(getresponse) {
      var html = '<a href="/#/parent/onboard/' + e.Id + '"  target="_blank">' + e.Number + "-" + e.Name + "-" + getresponse.code + '</a>';
      return html;
    })
}))
.then(function(result) {
  vm.owners = result.join('  ||  ');
})
.finally(function() {
  vm.isLoading = false;
});
```

You might also want use `async/await` to make the code a bit more readable. This would then look like

```
const listOfPromises = Promise.all(parents.children.map(async function(e) {
  const getresponse = await getparentById(e.Id)
  return  '<a href="/#/parent/onboard/' + e.Id + '"  target="_blank">' + e.Number + "-" + e.Name + "-" + getresponse.code + '</a>';
}))
const allResults = await listOfPromises
vm.owners = allResults.join('  ||  ')
vm.isLoading = false
```

This requires you to have your code inside an `async function` or use [top level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) functionality.

Comment: First solution solved problem. using await i will try later. Thanks :)